# Send std::vector<bool> over TCP

Tags: c++, vector, tcp

I have a very large (>1 million elements) std::vector that I need to send between two processes using TCP sockets. The reason I'm using std::vector is because I would rather send true and false across as single bits instead of taking up a whole byte (since the data size is so large).

I'm doing some small test cases so that I'm not limited by the maximum transfer size of TCP until I know that everything is working. Essentially, what I'm doing is

```
int vec[bits->size()]; 
copy(bits->begin(), bits->end(), vec);
```

so that it can be sent across the socket. Clearly, something isn't working. If vec contains 1 0 1 0 1 0 1, I receive 1000 0000 1000 0000 1000 0000 1000.

It's obviously expanding the bit vector in the copy. My question is this: how do I reinterpret the bit vector as something that can be sent over the socket, while keeping the size limitations of the original vector?

Comment: You can't for a generic implementation. Sorry.

Comment: However if you have a particular implementation in mind then it is probably possible.

Comment: `int vec[bits->size()];` Is this variable-sized array? What is type of bits?

Comment: Variable size arrays are not standard C++.  You should be explicit about the types of variables when you ask questions, I can assume, but I won't be able to know if my assumptions are right: please explicitly write the type of `bits` in your question.  Please ensure that the code snippet you post actually compiles.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Part of my problem was earlier in the code in unrelated sections. What I plan to do is make it work with expansion and see if it's too slow, and then revisit other ways to optimize.

Answer (score 2):

Even though `vector<bool>` stores the data as bits, this is transparent to accesses through iterators. Therefore it is working as intended that copying a vector of bools into an array of ints, converts each single bool value into an integer as 0 or 1. You may be able to get away with `unsigned char *bit_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&bits[0])` but it's not guaranteed. You will either need to process the vector and produce the bits yourself or use a new data structure. You could consider some kind of dynamic bitset (I believe there's one in Boost) or possibly `vector<bitset<N>>` which will be fairly easy to convert into a bit array using a for loop and bitset's to_ulong function.

Comment: +1 / "You may be able to get away with `unsigned char *bit_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&bits[0])` but it's not guaranteed." - I think it's pretty much guaranteed not to work, given the API for the reference class given in 23.3.8/1 doesn't overload `operator&`.  `vector<bitset<N>>` is a clever idea... cool!  Cheers.